# What does "taka" mean in this sentence

Tags: meaning

As topic,
"（アタシは当時、バイクなんて全然詳しくなかったけど、タカのその横顔が、すごく楽しそうに見えた）"

タカ in this sentence, what does it mean (it's not a name taka for sure)

Comment: It's almost certainly a person whose (nick)name is Taka. I can't think of any other ways to interpret this.

Answer (score 1):

タカ means "hawk" maybe, if it is not the nickname or the name of the man.

Maybe the woman confused ワシ (eagle) with タカ (hawk).

***I knew next to nothing about motorbikes, but I was interested in them when I saw the eagle's (hawk's) profile emblem.***

Comment: Hawk タカ is タカ{LH}(0) while name タカ（貴、考 etc）is タカ{HL}(1).